# Typescript: Make all properties optional unless explicited when using a literal type

Tags: typescript

I am trying to type the [search endpoint of Spotify's API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/search).

In their documentation, it says that the return payload is

```ts
export enum ResourceType {
  Album = 'album',
  Artist = 'artist',
  Playlist = 'playlist',
  Track = 'track',
  Show = 'show',
  Episode = 'episode',
  Audiobook = 'audiobook',

  Albums = 'albums',
  Artists = 'artists',
  Playlists = 'playlists',
  Tracks = 'tracks',
  Shows = 'shows',
  Episodes = 'episodes',
  Audiobooks = 'audiobooks',
}

interface ResourceTypeToResultKey {
  [ResourceType.Album]: ResourceType.Albums
  [ResourceType.Artist]: ResourceType.Artists
  [ResourceType.Track]: ResourceType.Tracks
  [ResourceType.Playlist]: ResourceType.Playlists
  [ResourceType.Show]: ResourceType.Shows
  [ResourceType.Episode]: ResourceType.Episodes
  [ResourceType.Audiobook]: ResourceType.Audiobooks
}

// Basically translates to -> Make every property possibly undefined
type SearchResults = {
  [K in SearchType as ResourceTypeToResultKey[K]]?: unknown // Don't pay attention to the value, I got it fine.
}
```

However, the documentation suggests that the real typing of the response is: *"we will only return the keys that you asked for"*.

That translates to: if the list is a literal type, we can narrow the typing and make the properties required.

Now my issue is: if the list is not a literal type, how can we force the response to still return the whole type with all properties marked optional ?

Basically, what I'm trying to do is:

```ts
declare const search: <T extends SearchType>(types: T[]) => Required<Pick<SearchResults, ResourceTypeToResultKey[T]>>
declare const types: SearchType[]
const result = search(types)
// the given type should be `SearchResults` (all properties marked optional)
result.tracks // Not ok, should be optional as it can't be determined for sure

const result2 = search([ResourceType.Track])
// the given type should be `{ tracks: unknown }`
result2.tracks // ok
```

Is this even feasible ?

Here is what my attempt: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwErAM4WVAY2ABUBPMYOAbwCg44BBAGwCM04BeOAcgENW03ADR1GsAJbZ4XPhKnDRABSa9STSdJ5gVajQvrEovAgGtOPGEdP64AZQAWEAO7nu2R05sBRMJIgATShlgX1xAmwZkf3EIFggIMxleKJi4hIVRZjZUbFd+bOwIuRhcpOLCkXplVXUpUq0dWpKbQ2MTeu5LNorRB2cO937vUICcVxC-QJ76SOjY+Pa8lPmEntEAVWxgKFdkLagFAF8aUEhYOBhySltgXkJ7MgpOUQAfTBw8QhIrgDostFe71w+CIj2Af2KgKwwK+YJ+1V0UihHxB3woP1apmRMNBvz6Tmxn1x6J8k2AhNRcNmqQWNBo4kQMG2ADNjJRoUS0SQINDkEwYABpYCkaiiADaHMpv3+qAAugAuIGcqkCHLiyWw6XFBVKqXohjldUozXozEmHUa4ngs3YI04rnwxoaC3Gq2OmoaW30CWuh34l32uH4r1wH2B36ksLAAPKiMjKZ22P65Zpc2Ky0O6krdo0Y40AD0+bgACFeNhxAR+EwRV1ENgVEzcjAIHAALQAPjgAFleCZKMAAG7bEVgKAQCiwEcQbDlljVuDIRCBZkM4D+GiXJ43O4Eey8-n1WjegVwBl2W73MFwMu6k3c-eC4VigWy2UAfkVi5MiGciDghbgAARCBEE6OAwFUa8YCZRkYj-ZsLnsSgB34ZBgCEOAAEk4AAcwgeBxHgFdEHBXM6UCAgVCgSgCBAqQ4C2Hd7EVAAeYgEBAGD-FybdLyudsAApNxwRViDFWUAEpOE7LAAEdkHEaj-BYxQKxMFjeN3B9sAwjMwWIHkcD5R9SDFYhZXbdsaAoqiaLo+BhOwRVNIeK5xJoWi63gajsGM8xGPuISrmwCSCyLeg4AAPTfMLEMoHDxCHeCrgYxw+X8OAWEoAADFztOyuABKrcCxwnGBxDGVA7j7DLx3KkD+FCnzjJ+LpTFyACADl8LgBIMMGdLMsoOq4P4a9ckIuBK1A+AsrgQImSgVBVwy5loAY-ByQ8+y4Ga-kACZ-IvXcBLDJNrSsc1QoAiLotimAkNwxKkAuFKBqYDK5uyqgLkupyF0Qb9fzgQ5srpPaYH21q-v-IsEiAA)

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NnBQoN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: It is EXACTLY it. Wow. I'm curious how it works.

Comment: `const T` makes the inline type a tuple and it it's not a finite length tuple then it's made optional. Wonderflame will explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let's see how we can check whether the array is a tuple (literal type) or not.

The difference is in the length of the array type. In the case of tuples, it is a finite number. Let's see something first:

```
type Case1 = 1 extends number ? true : false
//   ^? true

type Case2 = number extends 1 ? true : false
//   ^? false
```

`1` extends `number` since it is a sub-type of `number`, but not the reverse.

Examples with arrays / tuples:

```
type Case1 = [1, 2, 3]["length"];
//   ^? 3

type Case2 = (readonly [1, 2, 3])["length"];
//   ^? 3

type Case3 = number[]["length"];
//   ^? number

type Case4 = (readonly number[])["length"];
//   ^? number
```

Thus, we can conclude that if the `length` of the array is a finite number then it is a tuple, otherwise it is an array, the exact length of which we can't determine. Let's write a utility type for that:

```
type IsTuple<T extends readonly unknown[]> = number extends T['length'] ? false : true
```

Note that we are using `readonly` modifier to accept `readonly` arrays/tuples as well, since `readonly` version of an array / tuple is a super type of that array:

```
type Case1 = readonly number[] extends number[] ? true : false;
//   ^? false

type Case2 = number[] extends readonly number[] ? true : false;
//   ^? true
```

In the `search,` we must modify the generic parameter `T` to be constrained by `readonly SearchType[]` instead of `SearchType`. Also, we need to turn `T` into [const type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-5-0.html#const-type-parameters) to prevent the compiler from widening array types to an array of primitives. Note that `const type parameters` were added in Typescript `>= 5.0` and if you have the lower version you will need to use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when you pass the array into function. We need these changes to be able to use `IsTuple`, and the reason to add `readonly` was already mentioned previously:

```
declare const search: <const T extends readonly SearchType[]>(types: T) => ToBeDefined
```

We are going to [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the elements of `T`:

```
T[number]
```

To avoid code repetition we are going to store the result of the pick in the inferred parameter `R` using the [infer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) keyword:

```
Pick<SearchResults, ResourceTypeToResultKey[T[number]]> extends infer R 
 ? DoSomething
 : never // in theory, never will be reached
```

Next, we are going to see if `T` is a tuple, and if yes we will make the `R` non-optional, otherwise return it as it is:

```
Pick<SearchResults, ResourceTypeToResultKey[T[number]]> extends infer R
  ? IsTuple<T> extends false
    ? R
    : Required<R>
  : never;
```

And we are good to go:

```
declare const search: <const T extends readonly SearchType[]>(
  types: T
) => Pick<SearchResults, ResourceTypeToResultKey[T[number]]> extends infer R
  ? IsTuple<T> extends false
    ? R
    : Required<R>
  : never;
```

Testing:

```
declare const types: SearchType[];
const result = search(types);
result.tracks; // (property) tracks?: unknown

const result2 = search([ResourceType.Track]);

result2.tracks; // (property) tracks: unknown
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwErAM4WVAY2ABUBPMYOAbwCg44BBAGwCM04BeOAIgENW03ADR1GsAJbZ4XPhKnDRABSa9STSdJ5gVajQvrEovAgGtOPGEdP64AZQAWEAO7nu2R05sBRMJIgATShlgX1xAmwZkf3EIFggIMxleKJi4hIVRZjZUbFd+bOwIuRhcpOLCkXplVXUpUq0dWpKbQ2MTeu5LNorRB2cO937vUICcVxC-QJ76SOjY+Pa8lPmEntEAVWxgKFdkLagFAF8aUEhYOBhySltgXkJ7MgpOUQAfTBw8QhIrgDostFe71w+CIj2Af2KgKwwK+YJ+1V0UihHxB3woP1apmRMNBvz6Tmxn1x6J8k2AhNRcNmqQWAG4aDRxIgYNsAGbGSjQolokgQaHIJgwADSwFI1FEAG0uZTfv9UABdABcQO5VIEOXp9ClKNhsuKSpVMvRDHKmrg2pxPIxVhMBuluvRmPaZotqt+CKadp1xPBHo02Bd9p9P3xXstcPxAclQatpLCwDDbpJIymge9VupK1typjVOWaWdNGONAA9CW4AAhXjYcQEfhMMVdRDYFQs3IwCBwAC0AD44ABZXgmSjAABu2zFYCgEAosEnEGwNZYDbgyEQgVZTOA-holyeNzuBHs-MF9VoWqFcCZdlu9zBcGrhodvJPwtFEqF8vlAH5lWuTIgziILScBlnAAAiECIAA5PAYCqA+MAssyMSIBcnYwPYlCjvwyDAEIcAAJJwAA5hA8DiPAm6IOCRb0ruVxEdgxDINowAADzEAgIDIf4uRQLc-hQSu-6AU4iASvKfZcCgqAsNs3G8bkxAStwTBICRmHcPKojfnA7JMFsojKpYeH0YEBAqAJcAEFBUhwFsh72Mq7G2c28BcaASlwAJvBCYgK4HneVyST2AAUoh7jgyrEDQACUnB9ootYmOxQVHq+2AEbmVzEHyOACm+pASipsnyVAX59l5SB8VeiCsgpGC6UxLFsZxVU8TVuQGUZ9B6U19A5sAACOyDiAJ-jsRgPbGXANHjlA9E0BZVmUG59lRdgyrpQ8IXyvS63wAJ2CFeYjn3GFm1xfSx2FT8XSmAGoHlmFU4ztslwJQ97S-quiAAUBDKHT5BWCgATGdt5HmFrpGuCTrytdDK3eD902k9YGvdOs6fRc6N-v9YmIDQQA)

Comment: This is excellent. In the event that you publish an article on this, I'd love to share it. For the moment, I'll share this answer as one of the most qualitative answer I've ever found on StackOverflow.

Comment: Happy to hear that. Will notify you If I do so